# HTTP issue for custom domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, dns, openshift

For my openshift non scalable app(free tier) custom URL *www.mydomain.com* work fine I add two alias *www.mydomain.com* and *mydomain.com* at openhift side and proper `www` `CNAME` records at GoDaddy `dns` control panel. But when user type *http://mydomain.com* or *mydomain.com* it doesn't work. I think this problem will solve by adding A(HOST) IP entry. I continously check my app IP address using ping for week, it remains same. My question is, is it good to use hardcoded IP.
Is there is free third party service which automatically redirect user from http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com or Just hope user type www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Use this htaccess, it will redirect non www  to www & remember to change domain.com to your domain